# No log entries found for browsermobproxy with python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob-proxy

I have written this code in python,using undetected_chromedriver and browsermobproxy

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    server = Server(
        r"E:\YUNLIANG\yl.sc.addons\sourcecode\trunk\yl.sc.addons.tools\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\bin\browsermob-proxy")
    server.start()
    proxy = server.create_proxy({'trustAllServers': True})
    print(proxy.proxy)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=D:\SeleniumChrome")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy.proxy}')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

    chrome_driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, headless=True,
                              use_subprocess=False, version_main=121, port=9222)
    # 访问页面同时监听结果
    proxy.new_har("my_title",options={
        'captureContent': True,
        'captureHeaders': True,
        'captureBinaryContent': True
    })
    url = "https://www.inter.it/it"
    
    chrome_driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    result = proxy.har
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(result)
```

But when I try to validate through HAR Analyzer, it return a empty entries array

```
localhost:8081
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'log': {'version': '1.2', 'creator': {'name': 'BrowserMob Proxy', 'version': '2.1.4', 'comment': ''}, 'pages': [{'id': '666', 'startedDateTime': '2024-02-28T15:47:03.286+08:00', 'title': '666', 'pageTimings': {'comment': ''}, 'comment': ''}], 'entries': [], 'comment': ''}}
```

I hope to be able to intercept the website's ajax request and the server's response to the request